# Keeping a text field in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I thought this would be easy enough to do without seeking help, but I guess not. Adding the autofocus="true" tag works when the page initially loads but the text field loses focus if anyone clicks anywhere or opens a link. How do I force the field to keep focus?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @mat - sometimes *clients* request silly, silly things... You can't blame the programmer :)

Answer (score 2):

Someone ask why you want to do that .
the answer of-course is as a developers we need to deal we crazy demands by our clients :)

To the answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).click(function() { $("<THE-ELEMENT>").focus() });
});
```

In this case we add listener to all elements in the document :)

Answer (score 1):

Attach a click event listener on the document that focus's on the input box on click.

```
$(document).on("click", function()
{
     $("yourInputIdHERE").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#textbox").focus().on('blur', function() {
    $(this).focus();            
});
```

Comment: this is the best answer here so far.  You (OP) will want to bind an "onblur" event so every time that it LOSES focus. it regains it.  each other answer is... less preferred most likely.

Answer (score 1):

Handling all cases incase where some of the events are prevented from propagating till the document. Also handle the case where user switches tab and comes back.

```
$("#element").blur(function ()
{
    $("#element").focus();
});
$(document).bind('keydown mousedown mouseup click',function ()
{
    $("#element").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to try do, is attach an event handler to the `blur` event. Once you capture it, you can simply trigger a focus event on the same element that lost focus in the first place.

```
$("input").on('blur',function(){
   $(this).focus();
});
```

You might want to incorporate this with some form of validation so that once the user has entered the desired value, they will be able to leave the text field.

```
$("input").on('blur',function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.val() == ''){
     $this.focus();
     showErrorMessage("Please enter a value");
   }
});
```

If you don't implement some form of flag to enable/disable this behavior, you'll be locking the user into one field forever. There will be no (easy) way for them to move to a different area of the page.

**[Here is a small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YkwGe/2/)**,
you'll notice that once the text field has focus, it will keep it until a value has been entered.

Comment: @com - That example doesn't work because you forgot to place a `#` for the id selector and because you didn't include jQuery :) [Check out this fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/BTmmb/2/)

Comment: It has focus when it loads but when I click anywhere it loses it

Comment: Even on the links I posted? Note that you made some mistakes with your jsfiddle example that I mentioned in the previous comment.